# AngularJS : Weird custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I newbie to AngularJS .I have created my first custom directive with name of name `my-customer` by copying from side and paste it in my working file. When i try to built it myself i saw weird behavior because if I tried to access directive in with  `my-customer` it displays nothing on screen.

```
test.directive('my-customer',function(){
code...
}
```

when  I saw the original example ,author access the same directive with `myCustomer` name. How angular convert an html attribute to directive name .
because if I tried to use  `mycustomer` it still find nothing. What about controller which have more then one `-` in their name like `my-customer-a`

```
<div ng-app="myapp">

            <div ng-controller="Controller">
                <div id="test" my-customer></div>
            </div>


        </div>


var test = angular.module('myapp', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.customer = {
    name: 'Naomi',
    address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
  };
}]);
test.directive('myCustomer',function(){

    return{

        template:'Name :{{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular internally converts this `my-customer` like code to camelCase.
In this case of multiple `-` will get converted to camelCase.
Ex: `my-name-is-intekhab` will be converted to `myNameIsIntekhab`

Also you can use `:` or `data-`

This is from Angular site

> The normalization process is as follows:
>
> Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes.
>   Convert the :, -, or _-delimited name to camelCase.